# Naming a text file on CSHTML (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, razor, filenames, text-files

I have a page with a text area for title input and body input.

Saving a text file with those things is easy, the question is, how can I make the file to be named after whatever was placed in the title input?

I tried this:

```
@{
      var result = "";
  if (IsPost)
  {
    var title = Request["title"];
    var body = Request["body"];

    var filedata = title + "," + body + Environment.NewLine;

    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Request["title"]");
    File.WriteAllText(@dataFile, filedata);
    result = "Information saved.";
  }
}
```

(Note that `var title = Request["title"];` means that its requesting from a text input named "title"). What I want to get is that the input will also be the name of the file its saving.

But it seems that this area:

```
var dataFile = Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Request["title"]");
```

is not the correct way.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of pointers; firstly this sort of logic should be in a Controller, not in a View. Your Views are supposed to display information about your model, your Controllers carry out operations.

Secondly, the following should do the trick (in a Controller!):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(string title, string body)
{
    var fileData = title + "," + body + Environment.NewLine;

    var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(
        Server.MapPath("~/TextFiles"), 
        title.Replace(" ", "_") + ".txt");

    File.WriteAllText(fileSavePath, fileData);

    return this.RedirectToAction("SaveSuccessful");
}
```

Of note:

1. `Server.MapPath("~/TextFiles")` gives you the path to a TextFiles directory in the root of your web application where the files will be stored.
2. I've replaced spaces in the title which has been input with underscores.
3. This method redirects the user to an Action named `SaveSuccessful` on the same Controller

Of course you need error handling and all sorts of other things in there, but hopefully that helps.